# UIImagePickerController crashes when using PhotoLibrary as source

Tags: ios, crash, uiimagepickercontroller, unrecognized-selector

I'm using xcode 5.1 and tested the code both on ios7.1 and 7.0.2. The app crashes with UIImagePickerController in two scenarios on the device:

1) when `allowsEditing` is set to YES, after I crop a picture and press "Choose", as soon as it goes back to my own view, the app crashes

2) inside `UIImagePickerController`, when I go back from the photo list to the album list and I was at the bottom of the photo list, it crashes (no matter `allowsEditing` is YES or not). Note it does not crash if I scrolled the photo list up.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)photoPickPressed:(id)sender {

    if ([self isPhotoLibraryAvailable]) {

        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        NSString *requiredMediaType = (__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeImage;
        self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:requiredMediaType, nil];
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

#pragma mark - image picker delegates
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(){
        NSLog(@"finished image picking");
    });
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The crash message is

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:scrollViewDidScroll:] called!'

**Note**: it does **NOT** crash if I use camera even if I set `allowsEditing` to YES. Also it **ONLY** crashes on the real devices, not on the simulator.

Just to clarify (maybe unrelated), originally I declared the imagePicker as

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

, and it crashed. So I googled a lot, and a post says the controller might be recycled, and suggested to declare it in the class definition. So now I declared it in my class declartion:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
```

Thanks in advance.

Update: I tried to even put the invoke of imagePickerController to the root view of my app, and it still crashes with the same message. I shouldn't have any scrollable view loaded yet.

Comment: The odd thing is that a proxy of an object is being used instead of a real object. I'm thinking that an NSProxy is being used in the place of the UIImagePickerController, and so when it receives the scrollViewDidScroll messagem it can't handle it. This is probably just a bi-product of a larger, more obvious issue somewhere.

Comment: Thank you James! With your hint, I tried to create another new project and the above code actually runs without a problem. So apparently there is something wrong with the other places in my original app. Is there any hint on where I should start the investigation of the original app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of investigation and tryout, I am confirmed that it is caused by a third-party framework integrated to the app: even that empty app crashes with `UIImagePickerController` if I link that framework there.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you let us know what framework it was? I'm having that same problem.

Comment: Yeah, I was using that too, and then it just randomly went away.

Comment: @Jiaqi How did you figure out which framework it was?  I am not using that framework, but I am getting the same crash

Comment: @DanF I tried with brute force... Basically from the libraries that I was most unfamiliar with... Sorry this might not be that helpful.

Answer (score -1):

My recommendation would be to remove the `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method. It is completely optional, and will dismiss the image picker by default.

As well as this, I would recommend:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

According to the documentation, this method should be called on the presenting view controller:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the
>   presenting view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, James. But I have to use `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` to store the picked picture. I just simplified the code here to a `NSLog` (but crash still happens for sure). For the second one, wouldn't that dismiss my own view, instead of the presented `imagePickerController`?

Comment: How about a link or quote as to why `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is unnecessary if you need the resulting image?